# woocommerce_add_to_cart hook empties cart after product is added

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding a popup window in Woocommerce, every time a user adds a product to his/her cart, which displays the item which was added as well as related items which are set in an ACF field in the backend for each individual product.

My code in the **functions.php** looks as follows:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'display_more_modal', 10, 6);
function display_more_modal( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
    ?>
        <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal" data-remodal-options="hashTracking: false, closeOnOutsideClick: false">
            <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
                <h3 class="remodal-header">Item added to cart!</h3>

                <?php 
                /* Display all the items currently in your cart */
                global $woocommerce; 
                $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                ?>
                    <div class="cart-wrapper">
                        <?php
                            $item = new WC_Product($product_id);
                            $item_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($product_id));
                        ?>
                            <div class="row cart-item-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <img class="cart-image" src="<?php echo $item_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $cart_product->post->guid; ?>"><h1 class="remodal-cart-item-heading"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></h1></a>
                                    <?php 
                                    $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
                                    foreach($categories as $category) :
                                    ?>
                                        <?php if($category->slug == 'bikes') : ?>
                                            <?php 
                                                $frame_size = wc_attribute_label($variation['attribute_pa_frame-size']);
                                                $build_type = wc_attribute_label($variation['attribute_pa_build-type']);   
                                            ?>
                                            <p class="cart-meta">Frame Size: <?php echo $frame_size; ?></p>
                                            <p class="cart-meta">Build Type: <?php echo $build_type; ?></p>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    <span class="cart-amount"><?php echo $currency . $item->get_price(); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                <?php

                ?>
                <div class="btn-wrapper right">
                    <a class="remodal-cart-btn font-18" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>">View cart</a>
                    <a class="remodal-cart-btn font-18" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?>">Checkout</a>
                </div>

                <?php 
                $related_products = get_field('upsell_products', $product_id);
                if($related_products) :
                ?>

                <h3 class="remodal-header">You may also like</h3>
                <div class="row related-items-wrapper">
                    <?php
                    /* Display related items that the user may be interested in. */
                    foreach($related_products as $post) :
                        setup_postdata($post);
                        $related_product = new WC_Product($post['upsell_product']->ID);
                        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post['upsell_product']->ID));
                    ?>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <img src="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>" alt="">
                            <h3 class="upsell-title"><?php echo $post['upsell_product']->post_title; ?></h3>
                            <div class="btn-wrapper">
                                <a class="remodal-cart-btn font-12" href="<?php echo $post['upsell_product']->guid; ?>">View item</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    endforeach; 
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="btn-wrapper center">
                    <a class="remodal-cart-btn font-18" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/shop">Continue shopping</a> 
                </div>
        </div>
    <?php
  }
```

The problem I am having is that as soon as the user clicks on any of the links within the popup, Woocommerce empties the cart. So if you click on view cart, it'll take you to the empty cart template page. If the user continues browsing to an other page, you'll see in the top right it'll still say that there are 0 items in the cart.

A couple of pointers I have noticed so far:

1. When I log in as admin, this problem doesn't occur. Only for guest users.
2. When I remove the code save it and then re-add the code, the problem disappears but still causes problems when adding products incognito or using another browser/computer.

You can try adding a product to cart [here](http://swiftcarbon.com/za/shop/).

What am I doing wrong and what would be best practice as this huge chunk within an action looks rather messy?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue